# Invalid Shorthand Property Initiaizer - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, namespaces, dynamics-crm

I'm just getting a script error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid shorthand property initializer

using this piece of code in my script which I'm loading on a form in CRM Online with the new form rendering enginge.

```
if (typeof (MyCompany) == "undefined") {
    debugger;
    MyCompany = {};
}
MyCompany.Fn = {
    TestFunction: function () {
        debugger;
        MyCompany.Fn.TestFunctionStatic();
        this.TestFunctionStatic();
    },
    TestFunctionStatic: function () {
        console.log("Static!");
    },
}
```

Any ideas how this can happen?

Source for example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg309562.aspx#BKMK_CreatingScriptLibraries

Comment: Only issues I see is a missing semi colon and a trailing comma. And the parenthesis are not needed with `typeof MyCompany`.

Comment: where's the missing semi-colon?
after I'm closing the if statement?

Comment: After the object.